# Why is this not a syntax error? Comma inside function

Tags: javascript

See this javascript code I accidentally wrote.

```
myFunc = function() {weird: "weird string", console.log('hello');}

myFunc() // Prints 'hello'
```

I did not intended to put the `weird: "weird string",` part and removed it from my code. But was surprised that the initial one did not give a syntax error and ran fine. I am curious to know how.

Comment: Look up [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: @Bergi got it. thanks much!